# JPA ManyToMany bi-directional insert

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have problem and i could not find solution. I have bi-directional many to many anotation. I have this tables in DB (mariaDB):

- item
- section
- item_section

**Item part:**

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "item_section",
        joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "item", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "section", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
private Set<Section> sections;
```

**Section part:**

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "sections")
private Set<Item> items;
```

**PROBLEM:**

I create some Sections first. Than i want to create Item "within" this section. So i create instance of Item and add some existing Sections into set (Sections i get from DAO). If i persist the Item, records in item and item_section tables are created. But if i get some of affected section from DAO and iterate thru items set database changes are not here, Sections instances are in same state as before insert.

What did i wrong?

PS: i use eclipselink but i do not think it is interesting

**SOLUTION**

As @Chris said i called persist utimately but one side of direction already exist. No cascades was defined so during persist sections was not persisted nor merge. So best solution for my staless and JTA solution was use merge instead of persist on item and add MERGE cascade to sections collection...

Thanks everybody who came to help but especially to @Chris

Comment: Did you bother to set BOTH sides of the relation ? since you present no persistence code then no further comment is possible.

Comment: Thanks @NeilStockton but what persistence code you want? I simply do entityManager.persist(item) where entityManager is instance of EntityManager and item is instance of Item. what do you mean by "_ 
Did you bother to set BOTH sides of the relation ?_" I have setted both of them arent i?

Comment: Nobody can say whether you set both sides of the relation (in the objects to persist) since you don't post the persistence code (you only posted the classes). So you call persist on "item" ... and did you call persist on the other object (section)? Nobody can comment until you do

Comment: Oh i can see missunderstanding now. Sections are already persisted in time of creation of item. So:
1. i create sections one by one by persist to DB
2. i get sections by find function
3. i add "found" sections to item instance
4. i call persist with item instance

Comment: Setting both sides of the relationship is more than just adding the references to two instances' sets.  If the Section is existing and you want to make changes, you'll have to merge those changes into the persistence context.  Even though the change here isn't one that affects the database, your cache will not show changes to a Section's Items set unless you merge them in a transaction (or otherwise cause the Section to be refreshed/reloaded after the transaction).  Keeping a bidirectional relationship in sync comes at a relatively small cost to avoid having to hit the database.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the attribute cascade=CascadeType.ALL. You should try to change

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "item_section",
        joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "item", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "section", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
private Set<Section> sections;
```

to

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "item_section",
        joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "item", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "section", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
private Set<Section> sections;
```

then it works normally.

I found this mistake via the tutorial [Hibernate Many-To-Many Bidirectional Mapping Example](http://javabycode.com/java-frameworks/hibernate-4-tutorial/hibernate-many-to-many-bidirectional-mapping-example.html)

Hope this help

Comment: I can not do this. If i add this cascade than persist operation is called to all affected sections too. So i have duplicity in DB now. It is reason why i removed all cascased. I do not want to do any cascade. I want affected sections updated after insert into item table. Or am i wrong at some point?

Comment: You mean affected sections updated after insert have not references to items, right? Actually affected sections still have references to them. However, you are using FetchType.EAGER so that you get affected sections with same session when you persit item then they have not any reference. You should get them with other session this issue is resolved. Or you can replace EAGER to LAZY then everything works fine.

Comment: One more thing, for ManyToMany relationship I strongly recommend you to use LAZY instead of EAGER

Comment: yes, i have trouble that i affected sections have no reference to inserted item. After item insertion i throw entityManager away, change page (Vaadin view) and use find method on another entityManager to get sections. So i should be in another session right? Im using JTA. I changed EAGER to LAZY but issue is same... Thank for help.

Comment: The issue is the same because you cannot call persist on a detached entity, and cascade all ends up forcing persist to be called on the referenced entities.  Since the referenced entity has changed (youve modified its set to include the new Item you are calling persist on), you really just want to merge this change into the context.  Try using cascade merge on this relation, and calling merge instead of persist on the Item.  This will then pick up changes made to the referenced Section.

Answer (score 0):

Problem may be in incorrect using of eclipselink's shared cache which is enabled by default. Try to disable it by adding in `persistence.xml` following:

`<shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>`

When you persist or merge `Section` provider flushes it to database and add `Section` instance to shared cache so it can be retrieved from memory on next requests. When you persist `Item` you update only one side of the relationship, but the other side does not get updated, and becomes out of sync. In JPA, as in Java in general, it is the responsibility of the application or the object model to maintain relationships. If your application adds to one side of a relationship, then it must add to the other side. Read more about caching in bi-direction mapping in [this article](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Object_corruption.2C_one_side_of_the_relationship_is_not_updated_after_updating_the_other_side). 
I can offer following solutions of your problem:

1. Disable cache for whole application in `persistence.xml`
2. Manually refresh `Section` in DAO before retrieving it to user
3. Use cache correctly by updating both sides of relationship: